# Different table_areas on multiple page pdf

Tags: python-camelot

I would like to extract tables from a multiple page pdf. Because of the table properties, I need to use the `flavor='stream'` and `table_areas` properties to `read_pdf` for my table to be properly detected. My problem is that the position of the table is different on each page (the first page has an address head and not the other)

I have tried to provide several areas to the `read_pdf` function such as follows:

```
camelot.read_pdf(file, pages='all', flavor='stream', table_areas=['60, 740, 580, 50','60, 470, 580, 50'])
```

but this result as having 2 tables per page. How can I specify the table_areas for each page separately?

I have also tried to run several times `read_pdf` with different `pages`/`table_areas`, how ever then I cannot append the several result together to have a single objet:

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages='1', flavor='stream', table_areas=['60, 470, 580, 50'])
tables.append(camelot.read_pdf(file, pages='2-end', flavor='stream', table_areas=['60, 740, 580, 50']))
```

gives an error as append is not a method of resulting `tables`

Is there a way to concatenate the results of several call of the `read_pdf` function?

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please accept it (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as you noticed, you can't add items directly to the *TableList* object.

Instead, you can manipulate *TableList* *_tables* property (*_tables* is a list), in the following way:

```
my_tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages='1', flavor='stream', table_areas=['60, 470, 580, 50'])
my_tables._tables.append(camelot.read_pdf(file, pages='2-end', flavor='stream', table_areas=['60, 740, 580, 50']))
```

Now *my_tables* should consist of two tables.

Answer (score 0):

this answer works but you need

> my_tables._tables.extend(...)

instead of

> my_tables._tables.append(...)